# run the same program with different names in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I run the same program two times or more with different names when calling ps -ef, for examples I ran yes from one shell, and another yes from another yes, when I do ps -ef |grep [y]es I can see two copies with the same name and of course with different PID.
How can I name the first yes "one" and the second name "two" in shell?

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. What's the actual issue you're trying to resolve this way?

Comment: I'm building a program where I need to have more than one process with different parameters or args for each. I know I can name the program two or more different names and run them but I hope there a nicer way to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different parameters/arguments, and you want to be able to grep for them in your process list, then you want to use the -w flag. The ps(1) manual says:

> -w Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.

With that in mind, `ps -efww` or `ps axww` will give you the entire command line for each process, making it easy to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible in shell. Process can only change own proc title by calling `setproctitle (2)` syscall.
If you want to easy check, [here is Python](https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle) helper module. And [here some discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548294/python-changing-process-name-with-setproctitle) and alternatives.